# Selecting listbox members with partially matching string

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am currently using this method to match exact strings and select the index of which it belongs in a Listbox:

```
private void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string term  = searchbox.Text;
    int index = memlist.FindString(term);
    if (index != -1)
        memlist.SetSelected(index, true);
}
```

Would it be possible to have all partially matching strings selected?
How would I have to go about doing that?

Comment: You should just iterate through the `Items` property yourself.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code, which selects indexes of items, which start with your string, and then iterate over them and set items selected:

```
memlist.ClearSelected(); // clear previous selection
memlist.Items.Cast<object>()
       .Select((item, index) => new { Text = memlist.GetItemText(item), Index = index })
       .Where(x => x.Text.StartsWith(term, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(x => memlist.SetSelected(x.Index, true));
```

BTW Don't forget to set `SelectMode` of ListBox to multi select.

---

You can also select items in foreach loop:

```
var indexesToSelect = memlist.Items.Cast<object>()
      .Select((item, index) => new { Text = memlist.GetItemText(item), Index = index })
      .Where(x => x.Text.StartsWith(term, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      .Select(x => x.Index);

foreach(int index in indexesToSelect)
     memlist.SetSelected(index, true);
```

Comment: @Bitz thanks for accepting. Btw I updated with more common solution which will work if your listbox bound to some objects